# React nested forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

In my React (w/ typescript) application I've created a form using react-hook-form to manage all the logic of it.

I've then customised the select element with some css and other things. But, for the sake of question's simplicity, here the barebone component:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

type Props = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>;

const Select = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <select ref={ref} {...props}>
            <option value="">...</option>
            {props.children}
        </select>
    );
});

export default Select;
```

I've then defined another component that "specialise" the previous one, as:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

import Select from './select';

type Props = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement> & { label: string; errors?: string };

const SelectWitLargeData = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <Select ref={ref} {...props}>
           ...large amount of options
        </Select>
    );
});

export default SelectWitLargeData;
```

The problem is that the compiler gives me an error on <Select **ref={ref}** (<- here) ...>

```
Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement> | LegacyRef<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<HTMLSelectElement>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<HTMLSelectElement>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(140, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on 

type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Props, "label" | "key" | keyof InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement> | "errors"> & RefAttributes<...>'

(JSX attribute) RefAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>.ref?: Ref<HTMLSelectElement>
```

I've search for solutions online, and found many suggestions, but none of these work.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
Here's an example form to consume the components

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import Select from '@components/select';
import SelectWithLargeData from '@components/select-with-large-data';

type Form = {
    email: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
};

const Address: React.FC = () => {
    const { handleSubmit, register, setValue } = useForm<Form>();

    useEffect(() => {
        setValue('state', 'AL');
    }, [setValue]);

    const onSubmit = async (input: Form) => {
        console.log(input);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-10">
                <input type="email" {...register('email', { required: true })} />

                <SelectWithLargeData label="Provincia" {...register('state', { required: true })} />

                <Select label="Stato" {...register('country', { required: true })}>
                    <option value="IT">Italia</option>
                </Select>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};

export default Address;
```

**Edit 2**
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-rain-w9ej4

---

Answer (score 3):

As the edit queue is full, I'll add a separate answer. With this you can actually get the ref from HTML select element all the way up to the form. Is this what you are looking for?

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

type Props = Omit<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>, 'ref'>;

const Select = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, Props>((props, ref) => (
    <select {...props} ref={ref}>
        <option value="">...</option>
        {props.children}
    </select>
    )
);

type SelectHigherOrder = Props & { label: string; errors?: string };

const SelectWithLargeData = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, SelectHigherOrder>((props, ref) => (
  <Select {...props} ref={ref} >
    ...large amount of options
  </Select>
);
```

Also I would recommend to spread the props first and then add your own props, in order to avoid overwriting.

Comment: Thank you, especially "spread the props first and then add your own props" did the trick! I made the mistake to overwrite the ref by spreading the props afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [forwarding-refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) docs:

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

You should create `ref` inside `SelectWitLargeData` instead of forwarding it again.

Consider this example:

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

type Props = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>;

const Select = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <select ref={ref} {...props}>
      <option value="">...</option>
      {props.children}
    </select>
  );
});

type SelectHigherOrder = Props & { label: string; errors?: string };

const SelectWitLargeData = (props: Omit<SelectHigherOrder, 'ref'>) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null);

  return (
    <Select ref={ref} {...props}>
      1
    </Select>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NaYLEN)

You probably might have noticed that I have used `Omit<SelectHigherOrder, 'ref'>`. This is because you are using this type: `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>;`. And this type contains legacy ref type: `type WithLegacyRef = Props['ref']`  and when you use `{...props}` after `ref={ref}` you are actually overriding correct ref type which is `React.RefObject<HTMLSelectElement>`

Comment: It's almost perfect. But setting a value from react-hook-form SetValue does not work on first page load, I need to refresh to make the right option being selected

Comment: @Valerio You did not mention this requirement in your question. I don't know nothing about your structure of components. Please provide more context into your question

Comment: It was stated on the first line :)
But in the browser console now give me this error `Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Comment: added example form in the main question

Comment: @Valerio sorry, I don't understand. I have asked only about typescript compilation error, right? Could you please share the link to react sandbox? I can't reproduce the error

Comment: @capitan-yossarian here you are the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-rain-w9ej4

Comment: @Valerio I see that you are using Select inside of `SelectWithLargeData` and as a sibling. Is that by purpose?

Comment: Yes, as intended. The Select component is a general purpose element but "componentized" to make it easy to customize via css and whatnot, while SelectWithLargeData is a specific implementation. On my react app I use them both, in a manner similar to what I recreated in the codesandbox